# How to perform a cycle with a dos command?

Tags: command-line, cycle, dos

How to perform this with a dos command:

```
while (true)
myDOSCommand
sleep 5s
```

Comment: What do you mean by "MS-DOS"? Do you mean the NT Virtual DOS Machine (VDM)? Or do you mean *actual* MS-DOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:forever
myDOSCommand
sleep 5
goto forever
```